# Symbolic constants in C (#define statement)

Tags: c

After reading through some of K&R's The C Programming Language I came across the #define symbolic constants. I decided to define...

```
#define INTEGER_EXAMPLE 2
#define CHAR_EXAMPLE 2
```

...so my question is how does C know if I'm defining an int or a char type?

Comment: For your information you can accept only one answer, only click on one right...LOL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding these defines, it doesn't, the expanded macros doesn't have a type. The pre-processor which processes the #define is just replacing text within the source code

When you use these defines somewhere, e.g.

```
int i = INTEGER_EXAMPLE;
```

This will expand to

```
int i = 2;
```

Here the literal 2 (which in this context is an int) is assigned to an int.

You could also do:

```
char c = INTEGER_EXAMPLE;
```

Here too, the literal 2 is an int, and it is assigned to a char. 2 is within the limits of a char though, so all is ok.

You could even do:

```
int INTEGER_EXAMPLE = 2;
```

This would expand to

```
int 2 = 2;
```

Which isn't valid C.

Answer (score 10):

`#define`-d names have no types. They just define textual replacements.

What the compiler is seeing is the preprocessed form. If using GCC, try `gcc -C -E  somesource.c` and have a look at the (preprocessed) output.

<sup>In the 1980s the preprocessor was a separate program.</sup>

Read about the [cpp](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/) preprocessor, and [preprocessor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preprocessor) and [C preprocessor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) wikipages.

You could even define ill-defined names like

```
#define BAD @*?$ some crap $?
```

And even more scary you can define things which are syntactically incomplete like

```
#define BADTASTE 2 +
```

and later code `BADTASTE 3`

Actually, you want to use parenthesis when defining macros. If you have

```
#define BADPROD(x,y) x*y
```

then `BADPROD(2+3,4+5)` is expanded to `2+3*4+5` which the compiler understands like `2+ (3*4) +5`; you really want

```
#define BETTERPROD(x,y) ((x)*(y))
```

So that `BETTERPROD(2+3,4+5)` is expanded to `((2+3)*(4+5))`

Avoid side-effects in macro arguments, e.g. `BETTERPROD(j++,j--)`

In general, use macros with care and have them stay simple.

Answer (score 3):

`#define STRING VALUE`

is just an instruction for the pre-processor to replace the STRING with VALUE
afterwards the compiler will take control and will check the types

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't, this is the preprocessor.  The type of the constant is dependent on the context in which it is used.  For instance:

```
#define INT_EXAMPLE 257

char foo = INT_EXAMPLE;
```

will attempt to assign 257 in a char context which should generate a warning unless `char` has more than 8 bits on your computer.

Answer (score 2):

`#`Defines are nothing but literal replacements of values. You might want to use

```
static const
```

As it respects scope and is type-safe. Try this:

```
#define main no_main

int main()  // gets replaced as no_main by preprocessor
{
    return 0;
}
```

Should give you linking errors. Or you could try and fool your teacher by this

```
#define I_Have_No_Main_Function main //--> Put this in header file 1.h

#include"1.h"

int I_Have_No_Main_Function()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't.  The `#define` statements are processed before the compiler starts its work.  Basically the pre-processor does a search and replace for what you wrote and replaces it, for instance, all instances of `INTEGER_EXAMPLE` are replaced with the string `2`.

It is up to the compiler to decide the type of that `2` based on where it's used:

```
int x = INTEGER_EXAMPLE; // 2 is an integer
char y = INTEGER_EXAMPLE; // 2 is a char
```

Answer (score 1):

Preprocessor cannot know the type of the macro definition. Preprocessor will just replace all occurrence of 'CHAR_EXAMPLE' with '2'. I would use cast:

```
#define CHAR_EXAMPLE ((char)2)
```