# Using "#define" symbolic constants in ANSI C

Tags: c

After coming across symbolic constants via K&R's The C Programming Language I fail to see the usage/importance of them. I'd rather use a 'real' constant, say an integer, than using a `#define` statement. I can see why you would use say...

```
#define PI 3.14
```

as opposed to just typing "3.14" in your program but why would you use a `#define` statement if 
I could just use...

```
static const double PI = 3.14;
```

Are symbolic constants used today or is it just a feature of the language that was more useful 'back in the day'?

What do you recommend I should use for constants?

Comment: How different is this from your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19379353/symbolic-constants-in-c-define-statement)?

Comment: Another better option  `typedef const int PI = 3.14`

Comment: @devnull my other question is totally different to this one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#define` is old, and simply textual replacement processed by preprocessor. For example when you do `#define PI 3.14`, preprocessor simply replaces all occurance of `PI` by the number literal 3.14

`const` is newer, and compiler dependent. It could be evaluated at compile time, or at runtime. It also provides scope.

I personally use `#define` because it is guarrentee to be evaluated at compile time, and it has other flexible uses.